# Compare the strings of two tables in DB2 using SQL

Tags: sql, string-comparison

What I want to do is to compare the strings of two tables:

Imagine I have tables called students and professors. Both have an attribute called name. Now I want to get those Studentnames that contain the name of one of the professors.
Of course I tried

```
select s.name
    from students s, professors p
    where s.name like p.pame
```

but it says:

```
SQL ERROR: An operand of LIKE is not a string, or the first operand is not a column.
```

Comment: What is the structure of the tables?

Comment: I see that you have `p.pame` rather than `p.name`, please copy -> paste rather than retype code so as to avoid introducing typos.

Comment: @BobKaufman That was the point of my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.name
from students s
where s.name in ( select p.name from professors p);
```

Is this what you want?
Other wise, maybe you need to write a cursor to fetch a profsseor.name one at a time, then find matched student in a loop.